# HATEOAS Client Design

Tags: rest, api-design, hateoas

I have read a lot of discussions here on SO, watched [Jon Moore's presentation](http://oredev.org/oredev2010/2010/sessions/hypermedia-apis.html) (which explained a lot, btw) and read over Roy Fielding's blog post on HATEOAS but I still feel a little in the dark when it comes to client design.

**API Question**

For now, I'm simply returning xhtml with forms/anchors and definition lists to represent the resources. The following snippet details how I lay out forms/anchors/lists.

```
# anchors
<li class='docs_url/#resourcename'>
  <a rel='self' href='resource location'></a>
</li>

# forms
<form action='action_url' method='whatever_method' class='???'></form>

# lists
<dl class='docs_url/#resourcename'>
    <dt>property</dt>
    <dd>value</dd>
</dl>
```

My question is mainly for forms. In Jon's talk he documents form types such as (add_location_form) etc. and the required inputs for them. I don't have a lot of resources but I was thinking of abstract form types (add , delete, update, etc) and just note in the documentation that for (add, update) that you must send a valid representation of the target resource and with delete that you must send the identifier.

***Question 1:*** With the notion of HATEOAS, shouldn't we really just make the client "discover" the form (by classing them add,delete,update etc) and just send back all the data we gave them? My real question here (not meant to be a discussion) is does this follow good practice?

**Client Question**

Following HATEOAS, with our actions on resources being discover-able, how does this effect client code (consumers of the api) and their ui. It sounds great that following these principals that the UI should only display actions that are available but how is that implemented?

My current approach is parsing the response as xml and usin xpath to look for the actions which are known at the time of client development (documented form classes ie. add,delete,update) and display the ui controls if they are available.

***Question 2:*** Am I wrong in my way of discovery? Or is this too much magic as far as the client is concerned ( knowing the form classes )? Wouldn't this assume that the client knows which actions are available for each resource ( which may be fine because it is sort of a reason for creating the client, right? ) and should the mapping of actions (form classes) to resources be documented, or just document the form classes and allow the client (and client developer) to research and discover them?

I know I'm everywhere with this, but any insight is much appreciated. I'll mark answered a response that answers any of these two questions well. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you're pretty much spot on.

Browsers simply render the HTML payload and rely on the Human to actually interpret, find meaning, and potentially populate the forms appropriately.

Machine clients, so far, tend to do quite badly at the "interpret" part. So, instead developers have to make the decisions in advance and guide the machine client in excruciating detail.

Ideally, a "smart" HATEOS client would have certain facts, and be aware of context so that it could better map those facts to the requirements of the service.

Because that's what we do, right? We see a form "Oh, they want name, address, credit card number". We know not only what "name", "address", and "credit card" number mean, we also can intuit that they mean MY name, or the name of the person on the credit card, or the name of the person being shipped to.

Machines fail pretty handily at the "intuit" part as well. So as a developer, you get to code in the logic of what you think may be necessary to determine the correct facts and how they are placed.

But, back to the ideal client, it would see each form, "know" what the fields wanted, consult its internal list of "facts", and then properly populate the payload for the request and finally make the request.

You can see that a trivial, and obviously brittle, way to do that is to simply map the parameter names to the internal data. When the parameter name is "name", you may hard code that to something like: firstName + " " + lastName. Or you may consider the actual rel to "know" they're talking about shipping, and use: shipTo.firstName + " " + shipTo.lastName.

Over time, ideally you could build up a collection of mappings and such so that if suddenly a payload introduced a new field, and it happened to be a field you already know about, you could fill that in as well "automatically" without change to the client.

But the simply truth is, that while this can be done, it's pretty much not done. The semantics are usually way to vague, you'd have to code in new "intuition" each time for each new payload anyway, so you may as well code to the payload directly and be done with it.

The key thing, though, especially about HATEOS, is that you don't "force" your data on to the server. The server tells you what it wants, especially if they're giving you forms.

So the thought process is not "Oh, if I want a shipping invoice, I see that, right now, they want name, address and order number, and they want it url encoded, and they want it sent to http://example.com/shipping_invoice. so I'll just always send: name + "&" + address + "&" + orderNumber every time to http://example.com/shipping_invoice. Easy!".

Rather what you want to do is "I see they want a name, address, and order number. So what I'll do is for each request, I will read their form. I will check what fields they want each time. If they want name, I will give them name. If they want address, I will give them address. If they want order number, I will give them order number. And if they have any PRE-POPULATED fields (or even "hidden" fields), I will send those back too, and I will send it in the encoding they asked for, assuming I support it, to the URL I got from the action field of the FORM tag.".

You can see in the former case, you're ASSUMING that they want that payload every time. Just like if you were hard coding URLs. Whereas with the second, maybe they decided that the name and address are redundant, so they don't ask for it any more. Maybe they added some nice defaults for new functionality that you may not support yet. Maybe they changed the encoding to multi-part? Or changed the endpoint URL. Who knows.

You can only send what you know when you code the client, right? If they change things, then you can only do what you can do. If they add fields, hopefully they add fields that are not required. But if they break the interface, hey, they break the interface and you get to log an error. Not much you can do there.

But the more that you leverage HATEOS part, the more of it they make available to you so you can be more flexible: forms to fill out, following redirects properly, paying attention to encoding and media types, the more flexible your client becomes.

In the end, most folks simply don't do it in their clients. They hard code the heck out of them because it's simple, and they assume that the back end is not changing rapidly enough to matter, or that any downtime if such change does happen is acceptable until they correct the client. More typically, especially with internal systems, you'll simply get an email from the developers "hey were changing XYZ API, and it's going live on March 1st. Please update your clients and coordinate with the release team during integration testing. kthx".

That's just the reality. That doesn't mean you shouldn't do it, or that you shouldn't make your servers more friendly to smarter clients. Remember a bad client that assumes everything does not invalidate a good REST based system. These systems work just fine with awful clients. wget ftw, eh?

Comment: Perfect! So by documenting the different "classes" of forms (crud) and exposing them where available according to the domain and allowing clients to look for "known" forms seems to be an acceptable approach, as long as they utilize the form instead of assuming it. This is great. Luckily, for the time being, I am creating both the client and api.

Comment: Is creating objects inside the client code that map to the server's resources good practice? I would assume so, as this would allow the ability for the client to 'fill out' form fields that they understand easier. Or is this too much replication (ie. DRY). I guess in this sense it would be fine as I am really talking about two completely different applications (api, client), so DRY wouldn't apply.

Comment: Yea, the trick is writing to what the server actually asks and tells you to do, rather than what you think, at the time of writing, the server wants to do. The more you assume, the more fragile the system is and more resistant to change it becomes. But flexibility comes at a cost of coding and code complexity, which is why most folks don't bother.

Comment: If you can reuse code, reuse it. Just because your client and server may be joined at the hip via a shared library, doesn't mean other clients will. No reason to punish yourself.